# HTML Copy from list to another list?

Tags: html

Im not totally sure how to do this in HTML as im not fully aware of all the types of element. Essentially, i would like to have a list of data which a user can then highlight however many they wish and then click on a button and it would copy it over to a blank list.

What objects do i use for the 'lists'? I know how to do the copy over etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd say you can use a select with multiple choices like here
http://w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

and you'll have to do some code in JS

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want the lists laid out.  You can do it in a table or use the html list tags `<ol>` for an ordered list, or `<ul>` for unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in html with a "multiple" select box and a button for submission.

You will still have to have some kind of background processing that is not html.

To make it more dynamic (avoid the refresh) you would need to use JavaScript.

Once you start using JavaScript there are a whole host of new options.  You could implement the list as a list of clickable divs that change color/size/dissapear upon click.  But that would not be pure HTML.